# Common IDs across all categories in a column of Dataframe- Python

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with three columns as ID, Name and Social-Site, How can I find common IDs/ or the data associated for all Social- Sites/ or any of them. Data is following

```
ID  Name Social_Site
1   Jon  Facebook
1   Jon  Twitter
2   Bob  Twitter
2   Bob  Linkedin
3   Tony Facebook
3   Tony Linkedin 
4   Geon Twitter
4   Geon Facebook
4   Geon Linkedin
```

So, common Ids among all the sites are

```
ID Name 
4  Geon
```

and only among Facebook and Twitter is

```
ID Name
1  Jon
4  Geon
```

Really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
print (df.pivot(index='ID', columns='Social_Site', values='Name'))
Social_Site Facebook Linkedin Twitter
ID                                   
1                Jon      Jon    None
2               None      Bob     Bob
3               Tony     Tony    None
4               Geon     Geon    Geon
```

Edit:

For removal rows with `NaN` use [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
print (df.pivot(index='ID', columns='Social_Site', values='Name')
         .dropna())
Social_Site Facebook Linkedin Twitter
ID                                   
4               Geon     Geon    Geon

print (df.pivot(index='ID', columns='Social_Site', values='Name')[['Facebook','Twitter']]
         .dropna())

Social_Site Facebook Twitter
ID                          
4               Geon    Geon

print (df.pivot(index='ID', columns='Social_Site', values='Name')[['Facebook','Linkedin']]
         .dropna())

Social_Site Facebook Linkedin
ID                           
1                Jon      Jon
3               Tony     Tony
4               Geon     Geon
```

If need all columns, use parameter `subset` in `dropna`:

```
print (df.pivot(index='ID', columns='Social_Site', values='Name')
         .dropna(subset=['Facebook','Linkedin']))

Social_Site Facebook Linkedin Twitter
ID                                   
1                Jon      Jon    None
3               Tony     Tony    None
4               Geon     Geon    Geon
```

Comment: Right on the target, just one more thing, how can I control the removal of NAs, I mean what If I just want to see common between Facebook and Twitter, then in that case, how should I control dropna

Comment: You came like a Savior, I appreciate, the time you gave for this